# React Native project creating not working

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, iphone, react-native

Facing problem of creating project in  React Native (iOS ). i have installed the following commands successfully:

```
1.  /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

2.  npm install -g react-native-cli

3. brew install node

4. brew install watchman

5. brew install flow
```

When i run the command "react-native init AwesomeProject" , it shows following error;

```
-bash: react-native: command not found
```

FYI : In my mac home directory, it just create a file name "npm-debug.log".

I can't proceed on.

How i can create and run a project ?

[image]

My directory is: 
[image]

Comment: Have you installed sinopia? Maybe it will help. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/react-native-cli

Comment: Did you really run `npm install` before installing `node`? What's the output of `npm install -g react-native-cli` ?

Comment: @Evgeny Kuznetsov, no . 

and YSK, i tried that. Whatever, i solved my issue with redoing "sudo npm install -g react-native-cli" command. it works fine now.